# How to know I tap "taking photo button" with UIImagePicker

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

There are three delegate method with UIImagePickerDelegate.

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

This method tell you the piture you take.
 But when I tap the "taking photo button", how I know the event?

Answer (score 1):

You should

1) subclass UIImagePickerController

2) set showCameraControls = NO

3) create your own controls on this ViewController's view

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3**

My way is a bit hacky, but essentially I drill down the view hierarchy to find `CMKShutterButton`, then attach a method to the the appropriate control event.

See my post and solution here: [iOS, UIImagePickerController, is there a way to detect when user taps the take picture button without implementing custom controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488057/4018041) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489246/4018041.

Hope this helps!  Cheers.