# UIImagePickerController - Retake button on custom Overlay (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to implement a custom cameraOverlayView with a `UIImagePickerController`. I manage to hide the button and have my own interface , but a custom interface blocks the editing screen with the Preview option and the Retake. I noticed on some older posts adding two Notifications for "`_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem`", "`_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem`" and then adding and removing the overlay would fix the issue. But with Swift 3 I cannot seem to find how to access these notifications and the delegate from `UIImagePickerController` is very limited. Is there another way ?

Comment: In 2023 it now works perfectly fortunately. See answer.  Note that THIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77656045/getting-the-actual-camera-preview-frame-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller is also very useful when using the standard camera interface.

Answer (score 0):

##### Fortunately in 2023, it now works perfectly again:

```
///Standard camera picker which is aware of when the user "takes/retakes".
class OverlayPickerVC: UIImagePickerController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName:
                            NSNotification.Name(rawValue:
                            "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"),
                         object:nil, queue:nil, using: { [weak self] _ in
                // the user did tap the default shutter button
                // we're now in 'preview' mode
                self?.. for example, hide your crosshairs overlay
        })
        
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName:
                            NSNotification.Name(rawValue:
                            "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"),
                         object:nil, queue:nil, using: { [weak self] _ in
                // the user did tap the retake button
                // we're now in 'take a photo' mode
                self?.. for example, show your crosshairs overlay
        })
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it wasn't working for OP back in the 2010s, but it fortunately works perfectly today.

You can use the completely standard interface of UIImagePickerController but get control over the "take" "retake" modes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you cannot access the "Retake" event , so there is a need to create also a custom "Edit" screen. I have on the same customCameraOverlay , buttons for "Retake" and "Use it". So when the user stops capturing I hide the record and the cancel button and I present the retake and use it options, adding also a preview. So when the user clicks on retake I reverse the buttons again and remove the preview View. Likewise on "Use it" didfinishcapturing is being called

Comment: Fortunately this is (now) incorrect.  Fortunately you can (now) use the completely standard interface of UIImagePickerController but get control over the "take" "retake" modes.