# Getting the actual camera-preview frame when using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When using `UIImagePickerController()` it's easy to add an overlay image.

I'd like to dynamically get the "actual camera preview image area", i.e. indicated in a yellow box here:

[image]

(For example you might need to add an image guide overlay, crosshairs or such.)

If you poke around in Apple's views you'll soon see that `CAMPreviewView` is the best bet to get that frame.

Hence, I just cheaply find it using code like this that searches for "CAMPreviewView" in view stack. `pc` is the `UIImagePickerController`

```
if let foundFrame = pc.view.first(ofType: "CAMPreviewView")?.frame {
    yourOverlay.frame = foundFrame
}
else {
    print("Had to use a reasonable fallback ...")
    yourOverlay.frame = .. 
}
```

the `yourOverlay` is the

```
pc.cameraOverlayView = yourOverlay
```

(The yellow border image is indeed `yourOverlay` for the photo example above.)

This is a bit cheap and an anything could happen to Apple's code in the future.

Is there a better more authorized and standard way to add an "image overlay" on the image itself of UIImagePickerController and/or a more standard way to find the frame of the actual live preview?

Some code for the "CAMPreviewView" hack ...

```
extension UIView {

    var subviewsRecursive: [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.subviewsRecursive }
    }
    
    ///Find by type by string.
    func first(ofType: String) -> UIView? {
        return subviewsRecursive.first(where: {String(describing: $0).contains(ofType)})
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is really the only one. There is no public API to know the built-in preview view frame. The only possible alternative which gives you full control is to create a fully custom camera view using AVFoundation. See the [AVCam demo app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcam_building_a_camera_app).

Comment: I think you're right, @HangarRash - perhaps you should put it in as an answer (a negative result is very useful here). It would help googlers, I bet ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, there is really no way to achieve this as of 2024.

The only real "hack" is to find the view of type

```
CAMPreviewView
```

You can easily do that with code like ...

```
extension UIView {
    var subviewsRecursive: [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.subviewsRecursive }
    }
    ///Find by type by string.
    func first(ofType: String) -> UIView? {
        return subviewsRecursive.first(where: {
           String(describing: $0).contains(ofType)
        })
    }
}
```