# How to get the crop rect of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to draw over the imagePicker image section. I know that the image picker has an overlay view which you can use. However I want to add to the image section area only, so I need to get the crop rect.

I know there is a value in ImagePicker:

```
UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.cropRect
```

However I don't know how to access it and how to get the value out of it.

Comment: Is this a similar question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77656045/getting-the-actual-camera-preview-frame-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: This is different problem, I will look at my notes and compose a proper answer.

Answer (score -2):

## The brief answer is:

`UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` or `editedImage`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollereditedimage?language=objc

## Sample code, Swift 4.x

From long ago, I had found Xcode to be finicky about the swift version, so even though I used Swift, I use the O-C naming. Here's the code in my projects:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String:Any]) {
    print("Selected Image's MetaData: \(info)")
    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {

(blah blah blah)
```